# How do I create a login form in Java using file stream?

Tags: java, netbeans

Hello i am a new java student i have  been working on a library system containing ( users - library workers and books ) so i am trying to create a log in form i already have an array list but i did a file stream ( to clarify i let the new user to register and his/her information will be saved to the file like this  ID     Name     Password    Age ) so i have tried to do something as this method in the  library users class

```
      private Scanner x;
      private String user_name , password ;
      public void openfile(){
      try {x= new Scanner (new File ("E:\\javaapplication1
      \\test\\professors.txt"));
              }
      catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("couldn't find file");
      }
      }
      public void checklog ( String username , String password ){
       String a , b ,c ,d ;


       while(x.hasNext()){
       a = x.next();
       b = x.next();
       c = x.next();
       d = x.next();

       if ( b == username ||c == password ){

        System.out.println("Loggin successful ");

       }
       else
           System.out.println("Loggin failed wrong id or password ");
        break;
```

and then call it like this in the main with the full code

```
        System.out.println ("Enter your name ");
        check_name = reader.next();
        System.out.println ("Enter your password ");
        check_password =reader.next();
         lib_us professor ;
             professor = new lib_us(); 

             professor.openfile();
             professor.checklog(check_name, check_password);
```

i get all passwords wrong i save them like 4  id name password and age that's why i created a b c and d ...

i am still new in this kind of log in forms so please specify me a  solution and if you need the whole code please ask for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your `checkLog()` method you have the statement `if(b == username || c == password)` should be `if(b.equals(username) && c.equals(password))` OR  `if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && c.equalsIgnoreCase(password))` for case sensitive or not (use the equals() method for case sensitivity or the equalsIgnoreCase() method for non case sensitivity).

Understand why that is? Because in your original statement you are saying only one of them has to be true in order for it to be a successful login. With the revised one both of them must be true. Also you should not use the operator `==` to compare two strings to see if they are the same string. That will only compare their addresses.

EDIT:
If your file is kind of like what is shown below:

12 Name Pass 12

13 Namez Passz 13

14 Namezz Passzz 14

Try this code to read it in and compare:

```
private Scanner x;
private String user_name, password;
public void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        x = new Scanner(new File("FILE PATH"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println("Couldn't find file"); System.exit(0);}
}

public boolean checklog(String username, String password)
{
    String temp;
    String[] info;

    while(x.hasNext())
    {
        temp = x.nextLine();
        info = temp.split(" ");

        //info[0] = id, info[1] = username, info[2] = password, info[3] = age;
        //Right here that means the username and password is correct
        if(info[1].equals(username) && info[2].equals(password))
        {
            System.out.println("Login Successful");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Login failed wrong id or password");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks for answering my question :) and yeah i got the idea but it still getting me a wrong id or password   like for example i have an  account having an  22          michael            fredy           26          written exactly like so in the file  showing ID , name , password , age so is that the  spaces  i put is the problem or what ?

Comment: @RaymondHaniArtin So if it is all in one line i have edited my answer to show what you should do.